# Pass Concatenated Variable and String as Argument to Template Helper

Tags: meteor, spacebars

If I try to pass a Variable and String as an argument to a template helper I end up with the string literal:

```
{{#ContainerSurface class='progressBarContainer {{namespace}}'}}
```

Ends up as `<div class="famous-surface progressBarContainer {{namespace}}">`

If I try to do

```
{{#ContainerSurface class={{'progressBarContainer ' + namespace}}
```

I end up with error:

> => Errors prevented startup:
>
> While building the application:
>      client/cordova/pages/widgets/progressBar/progressBar.html:2: Expected identifier, number,
>      string, boolean, or null
>      ...sBarContainer' class={{'progressBarContai...
>      ^
>
> => Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

I can make a Template Helper that returns the String + Variable, but that makes for messy code as I need to do this more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do 1 helper , and use [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) Package,to use on other templates.

```
Template.foo.helpers = function () {
 thisHelperIsAvaibleEverywhere:function(){
     return "Test";
  }
};
Template.foo2.inheritsHelpersFrom("thisHelperIsAvaibleEverywhere");
```

Now just declare 1 template helper, and inherit to the others templates.

Where `foo2` it the name of the other template.